# Anchor in component link not showing on Java application (dxa 2.0.3) with dxa model service 2.2.2

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, dxa2.2, linking

We're trying to implement Anchor Link on our existing Link Component by Enabling Anchor Feature in `cd_link_conf.xml`

This is our configuration looks like

```
<Publications OverrideDiscoveryService="true">
    <Publication Id="33">
        <Host Domain="mysite.test" Port="80" Path="" Protocol="https" />
        <Linking ComponentAnchors="true" AddComponentLinkInfo="true" />
    </Publication>
</Publications>
```

Link schema
[image]

and our link model class

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Link extends AbstractEntityModel {

    @JsonProperty("linkTekst")
    private String linkTekst;

    // url property; neem externeLink als interneLink niet bestaat.
    @SemanticProperties({
            @SemanticProperty("interneLink"),
            @SemanticProperty("externeLink")
    })
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    @SemanticProperty("interneLink")
    private EntityModel embeddedLink;

    @JsonProperty("alternatieveTekst")
    private String alternatieveTekst;
    @JsonProperty("linkStyle")
    private Tag linkStyle;
}
```

We came with 2 problems:

- Anchor hash is not added in the url
- url always use domain defined by `cd_link_conf.xml`. It's not dynamic following where the web application runs (e.g. on localhost, urls points to mysite.test domain instead of localhost)

Is there anything that I miss?

Specs:

- Java application uses dxa 2.0.3 framework.
- Dxa Model service 2.2.2

Answer (score 3):

In general, CD Linking generates absolute URLs if you define Publication mappings in `cd_link_conf.xml`.

If you prefer server-relative URLs (which is often the case), you should *not* define any `Publication` elements in `cd_link_conf.xml` (Maybe it also works if you do define `Publication` elements, but no `Host` elements; never tried that).

Regarding `ComponentAnchors=true`: I’m not sure if you can make that work with DXA (again, never tried that).

Note that link resolving is typically done in the DXA Model Service, so you will have to use the DXA Model Service’s `cd_link_conf.xml`.

Comment: The `cd_link_conf.xml` that I mentioned was indeed from DXA Model Service. I assume this would be officialy supported by the product?

Comment: Changing the `cd_link_config.xml` of the DXA Model Service, you mean? Yes, that is supported. But not all features of CD Linking have been tested icw DXA.